# Find variance of a normal distribution

Tags: python, statistics, normal-distribution

If we have a normal distribution defined by:

```
mu = 22
sigma = 20

def y(x):
    otv = 1/(sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)) * np.exp( - (x - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2))
    return otv

x1 = np.arange(0,50)
y1 = y(x1)
```

How can we use Python to find mu and sigma out of the given set of data (y1, x1)?

Comment: As it is stated, you have x = grid of values, and y = density at those values. The mean you want is the mean of x *with weights equal to y*, so that values with greater density get greater weight. Looking at the numpy docs, it looks like `mean` and `std` do not accept weights as an argument, but `average` does. So call `average` to get the weighted mean (i.e. mu), and then calculate the weighted s.d. (i.e. sigma) in the ordinary way, as the weighted mean of (x - mu)^2, or as E[X^2] - E[X]^2.

Comment: @xap If Robert's comment is accurate, please update your question to include this information to make it more clear what your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.std` gives the standard deviation of an array.  `numpy.average` gives its average.  Both take all sorts of additional arguments.

```
>> y1.std()
0.00352871767572693

>> y1.mean()
0.0157037359404068
```

Comment: yeah, i know about this however, i still can't find a way to compute exact mu or sigma using np.average (end up with incorrect values). maybe you can write a code?

Comment: I don't think this is right. `numpy.std` doesn't accept weights as an argument, so the problem as it is stated can't be solved with it. I've tried to outline what seems like a workable approach in a comment.